# set attribute with .href and .attr('href') and jquery ID selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to use javascript and jquery to set the href attribute of tag  since I need to download pictures from canvas.However, I confronted some problems. I couldn't figure out the reason, so I post my question here.

1. If I use id to set the listener, the listener function doesn't catch the event, just like the png button beneath.
2. Compare the jpegBtn2 and jpegBtn, I used plain javacsript to set the former href attribute and for the latter one, I used jquery to do the manipulation. Both methods can download pictures, but the picture downloaded by the jpegBtn2 method couldn't open correctly. Later I checked out the chrome console, I found that the href of jpegBtn2 remained "#", but the href of jpegBtn changed.I had no idea with this.

Here is my code:

```
if(!setDownloadDialogOrNot){
    $('div.dialogBtnSet').append('<a class="jpegBtn2" id="jpegBtn2Id" type="button" href="#">close</a>');
    $('div.dialogBtnSet').append('<a class="jpegBtn" type="button" href="#">jpeg</a>');
    $('div.dialogBtnSet').append('<a id="pngBtn" type="button" href="#">png</a>');
    setDownloadDialogOrNot=true;
};

$('.jpegBtn2').on('click',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(1);
    $('.jpegBtn2').attr('download',filename+'.jpeg');
    document.getElementById('jpegBtn2Id').href=document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});

$('.jpegBtn').on('click',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(1);
    $('.jpegBtn').attr('download',filename+'.jpeg');
    $('.jpegBtn').attr('href',document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});

$('#pngBtn').on('click',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(0);
    $('#pngBtn').attr('download',filename+'.png');
    $('#pngBtn').attr('href',document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

For binding events to elements added dynamically you need to use 
`$(initallyLoadedContainerElement).on('click', 'selector',function(){})`

http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

```
$(document).on('click', '.jpegBtn2',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(1);
    $('.jpegBtn2').attr('download',filename+'.jpeg');
    document.getElementById('jpegBtn2Id').href=document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});

$(document).on('click', '.jpegBtn',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(1);
    $('.jpegBtn').attr('download',filename+'.jpeg');
    $('.jpegBtn').attr('href',document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});

$(document).on('click', '#pngBtn',function(){
    setDownloadCanvas(0);
    $('#pngBtn').attr('download',filename+'.png');
    $('#pngBtn').attr('href',document.getElementById('downloadCanvas').toDataURL('image/png'));
    $('div#downloadDialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I know the answer to my first question, but what about the second question? I still can't figure out~~